# Nothing is working for, ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda

I am using windows 10. My pip version is 20.2.4 and the python version is 3.8. How can I upgrade TensorFlow from 2.1 to 2.2 in anaconda?

I tried to upgrade TensorFlow, then I got the warning:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voXDp.png)

I again tried to run my code in jupyter notebook. And it shows the above import error.

Answer (score 1):

To install tensorflow on Windows. Follow the official website of [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

Or simply follow the below steps.In Anaconda, create a virtual environment using conda

```
conda create --name tf python=3.8
conda activate tf  # activate tf environment
pip install tensorflow # install latest version of Tensorflow 2.4
import tensorflow
from tensorflow import keras
```

Comment: This just solved my problem in VsCode terminal  when trying using Anaconda navigator didn't